# Mongodb Or operator in Find Query

Tags: mongodb

I have a query as below.

```
    Post.native(function(err, collection) {

        collection.find({
            $or: [ { id :id }, { parentid : id} ]
        },  function(err, result) {
            if (err)
                console.log({error: err});
            console.log(result);
        });
    });
```

But this returns zero results , even though i have one result satisfying {id : id} and two results satisfying {parentid : id}. I need three results to be printed.

Please correct me if my query is wrong. Any help would be appreciated.

Please help. Thanks a lot

Comment: Most likely `id` is `null` or `undefined` or a value other than the one you think in the enclosing scope, otherwise you need to post additional code that shows the value of `id`.

Comment: id is not null or undefined when i tried findOne for id it is displaying the respective result.

Comment: Are you using a ODM such as mongoose? Is this being run on the MongoDB console or a nodes application?

Comment: This is being run in node.js application only

Comment: Update your question with a document example you use for better answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some of the most common things I would do to debug this problem.

If you use the native driver and the fields you are querying are MongoIds, you need to ensure that ids are instances of `ObjectId`, i.e.

`id = new mongo.ObjectID(id)`

Also, mongodb natively stores its id as `_id`. Did you specifically create an `id` field?